# Working 2sum solver

Tags: python, k-sum

This is my first working 2sum solver. It works by finding the difference for our `target` in `s` to determine if that 2sum exists.

Suppose our `target` is -5. I start with the first index in `s` and use subtraction, **(-5-(-8) = 3)**, and the result is 3. The code will check the difference in `s`. If the difference exists in the list `s` then the output is yes.

```
s = [-8,3,5,1,3]
target = -5

for j in range(0, len(s)):
  if target-int(s[j]) in s[j+1:len(s)]:
   print('yes')
   quit()

print('no')
```

I fixed a bug where a false yes was returned when `int(s[j])` was equal to `target-int(s[j])`. I did this by `s[j+1:len(s)]` An example would be our `target` would be 4, but our input for **s** was `[2]`. It would say yes because `int(s[j])` was equal to `target-int(s[j])`.

Is it possible to write this code all in one or two lines of code?

Comment: When mentioning about `target = 4` for `s = [2]` which gives you `yes`,  did you describe the wrong case? Because your current approach will output `no` for that input case.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm stumped on it. I got writer's block. I'll figure out how I should best explain it.

Comment: Why the `int(...)` conversions if the inputs are already integers? Is the function meant to also work with non-integer inputs? If so, is the rounding behaviour of `int` really what you want?

Answer (score 6):

Translating your code directly into a one-liner:

```
s = [-8,3,5,1,3]
target = -5

is_2sum = any(target - s[j] in s[j+1:len(s)] for j in range(len(s)))
print(is_2sum)
```

A few notes:

- The loop is now translated into a generator expression: we record whether every difference is present in the remainder of the list and combine this with `any`, which will check if the resulting list contains a `True`.
- In particular, note that we do *not* construct a list by list comprehension inside the call to `any`. Indeed, by using a generator expression we allow for an early exit as soon as a `True` value is found, potentially speeding up quite a bit the execution on positive instances.
- Your approach runs in quadratic time. However, this algorithm can be further optimized to run in linear time (see e.g., a similar question on [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13586/472)).

If you are fine with a quadratic time algorithm, another alternative is to brute-force every pair. It is straightforward to generalize such an algorithm to k-sum as well. So just for fun, we might also do:

```
from itertools import combinations 

s = [-8,3,5,1,3]
target = -5

is_2sum = any(sum(p) == target for p in combinations(s, 2))
print(is_2sum)
```

As stated, this is not highly scalable, but it should very easy for a beginner to read and to understand (if that matters).

Comment: I was trying to make it a little faster than O(n^2) time by stopping one element short because of `s[j+1:len(s)]`.

Comment: @TravisWells Such an approach runs in big Omega of n squared, so that won't help.

Answer (score 4):

- You should make this a function.
- You should use 4 spaces for indentation.
- If `s` becomes a count of numbers in a dictionary, then `in` becomes performs in \$O(1)\$ time, where lists perform in \$O(n)\$ time.
- Using `quit` isn't really idiomatic, and was added to make exiting the REPL easier.
- Rather than `for j in range(0, len(s))` you can use `for item in s`.
- Use better variable names, `s` and `j` are just meh.
- You can use a comprehension, with `any` to reduce noise.

```py
import collections


def has_two_sum(items, target):
    items = collections.Counter(map(int, items))
    for item in map(int, items):
        remainder = target - item
        if items.get(remainder, 0) >= (2 if item == remainder else 1):
            return True
    return False


if has_two_sum(s, target):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Or you can write it in on of these one liners, which look like garbage:

```py
s=collections.Counter(map(int,s));print(['no','yes'][any(map(lambda i:s.get(t-i,0)>=1+(i==t-i),s))])
f=set();print(['no','yes'][any(map(lambda i:(t-i in f,f.add(i))[0],s))])
```

Comment: This will have the same bug that the OP described where a number plus itself can equal the target, giving a *"false yes"*. You can fix it by putting each number into the set after testing it, instead of putting them all in at the start.

Comment: Yes @kaya3, there is that bug indicating insufficient testing.  On the other hand I like presenting code that is well formatted rather than golfed into a minimum number of lines. I do have one formatting quibble, I don't like simplistic if/else blocks.  `print(f'{"yes" if has_two_sums(s,target) else "no"}')`

Comment: No need for a format string there - `print("yes" if has_two_sums(s, target) else "no")` is equivalent.

Comment: @kaya3 Ah yes, my last 2 sum didn't have that characteristic. Simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will solve your problem:

```
# Using ternary operator to condense the print's
two_sum = lambda s, target: print('yes') if any(map(lambda x: target-x in s and s.count(x)>1, s)) else print('no')

# If s.count(x) is 1, it means the subtraction resulted in the same element took that time for the operation, which we don't want to happen. So the count must be greater then 1

two_sum([-8, 3, 5, 1, 3], -5)
# Output is "yes"

two_sum([2], 4)
# Output is "no"
```

So, we wrapped the function in a lambda, used another lambda in the map call and preserved all items in the list, checking if the output matches another element besides the one took in for the calculation.

### Benchmark

I was wondering if @Juho's answer provided a faster function, so I benchmarked both.

So:

```py
two_sum = lambda s, target: any(map(lambda x: target-x in s and s.count(x)>1, s))

is_2sum = lambda s, target: any(target - s[j] in s[j+1:len(s)] for j in range(len(s)))

# The print's aren't necessary for the benchmark.
```

Then, I ran both at Google Colab with the following code:

```py
two_sum = lambda s, target: any(map(lambda x: target-x in s and s.count(x)>1, s))

is_2sum = lambda s, target: any(target - s[j] in s[j+1:len(s)] for j in range(len(s)))

test_function = two_sum
# test_function = is_2sum

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    setup = "from __main__ import test_function"
    average=0
    for i in range(0,100):
      average=average+timeit.timeit("test_function([-8, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3], -5)", setup=setup, number=1000000)
    print(average/100)
```

The method `timeit.timeit()` will run each function 1.000.000 times, then I record the outputs of 100 iterations (so, we actually ran the function 100.000.000 times) and take the average.

#### Results:

For the function `two_sum`:
First run: `0.9409843384699957`
Second run: `0.948360692339993`

For the function `is_2sum`:
First run: `0.9963176720300112`
Second run: `0.998327726480004`

As you can see, there is an increase in performance for `two_sum` function, whether this comes from the use of `map()` and avoiding lists operations, I don't know, but it's a bit faster.